# Android studio clone component programmatically

Tags: java, android

basically I'm trying to add this example of item in a linear layout inside of ScrollView from code but I don't know how to do it. is there any way on how to clone it  ?
Example :

- [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlAMS.png)

Example line in XML:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"


            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/match1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/listviewicon"
                android:src="@drawable/draw_header"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/score2"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="22dp"

                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="13 - 13"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#F4F1E5"
                android:textSize="16sp"

                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/kda1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/agent2"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"


                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/match1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/reyna" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/rank2"
                android:layout_width="27dp"
                android:layout_height="27dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/agent2"

                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/tx_competitivetier_large_17" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rating2"
                android:layout_width="27dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="+1"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#F4F1E5"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/agent2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rank2"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.157" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/draw"

                android:layout_width="81dp"
                android:layout_height="23dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="DRAW"
                android:textColor="#DDBF64"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/score2"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/score3"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="13dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="147dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="147dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="SCORE : 0,000"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/kda1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="22dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="144dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="144dp"
                android:autoText="false"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="KDA : 00/00/00"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/score3"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/match1" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

To be honest it is very hard to keep creating each view from code and add it to root + I don't know how to proporly place it

Comment: "a linear layout inside of ScrollView"; would a `RecyclerView` be the answer?

Comment: That'ts why views like [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) or [ListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView) (older but fyi) exists, you can create the logic to create a list and populate then the items are displayed with the help of mentioned views